# I need help getting this program to print "Invalid Response" when the user does not enter "yes" or "no", how can I simply do this?

Tags: java, if-statement

I need the code to print "Invalid Response" if the user does not enter "yes" or "no", and wish to know the simplest way you can do this. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Closet
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
      System.out.println("Welcome to your closet! Let's see what you can wear!");
      System.out.println("Is it cold outside?");
      String cold = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
      if (cold.charAt(0) == ('Y'))
      {
         System.out.println("You should wear long sleeves."); 
      }   
      if (cold.charAt(0) == ('N'))
      { 
         System.out.println("You should wear short sleeves.");
      }  
   }
}
```

Comment: That is some funny looking JavaScript

Comment: so what goes hand in hand with an if statement?

Comment: Why are you testing only first character? What if user typed `You will never know!!!`? Compare entire response to what you expect to get. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832) or if you don't want to manually change its case you can use something like `if("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(response)){...}`.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html especially part about `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `main` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to your closet! Let's see what you can wear!");
    System.out.println("Is it cold outside?");
    String cold = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    if (cold.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("You should wear long sleeves.");
    } else if (cold.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("You should wear short sleeves.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid response");
    }
}
```

So, the valid entries are "yes" and "no" and isn't case sensitive (You could send "YES", "Yes", etc)